# Add Azure user to resource group with nodejs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk

Using the Node.js SDK, I've created a user and a resource group. How can I now assign the user to the resource group as an owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/Documentation/ServicePrincipal/spCreate.js#L134).

```
authzClient.roleAssignments.create(scope, assignmentGuid, roleCreateParams, function (err, roleAssignment, req, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('\nError occured while creating the roleAssignment: \n' + util.inspect(err, { depth: null }));
    return;
  }
```

According to your need, you need the example.

`Owner` role id is `8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635`.

`scope` should be like this `/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup1`.

Replace application id to your user object id.

Also, you could use Azure rest API to do this, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest#create-a-role-assignment).